# Add diagonal difference of matrix

Tags: ruby, loops, matrix

HackerRank Diagonal Difference Problem.

Print the absolute difference between the sums of the matrix's two diagonals as a single integer.

Link to problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem

I have been trying for hours to solve this problem in Ruby. I happened upon an answer that someone else figured out.

I am now please asking for help in understanding how this method works. I want to understand what it is doing. I am confused by the entirety of the loop.

```
a.each_with_index do |array, index|
  left_right += array[index]
  right_left += array[-index-1]
```

Could someone please explain step-by-step what is happening in this block of code so I can learn and better understand Ruby? Thank you.

```
def diagonalDifference(a)
  left_right=0
  right_left=0
  a.each_with_index do |array, index|
    left_right += array[index]
    right_left += array[-index-1]
  end
  v = right_left - left_right
  return v.abs
end
```

Comment: Plug `[[1,2],[3,4]]` into `diagonalDifference` and follow the steps. If you don't know how `each_with_index` works then have a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [main skew diagonal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkewDiagonal.html) (or *main secondary diagonal*) of a `nxn` matrix `a` is comprised of the elements `a[n-1][0]`, `a[n-2][1]`,..., `a[1][n-2]`, `a[0][n-1]]`.

Part of the problem is that the variables have not been given descriptive names. I would write that as follows.

```
def diagonal_difference(arr)
  main_diagonal_sum=0
  main_skew_diagonal_sum=0
  arr.each_with_index do |row, i|
    main_diagonal_sum += row[i]
    main_skew_diagonal_sum += row[-i-1]
  end
  (main_diagonal_sum - main_skew_diagonal_sum).abs
end
```

I expect `row[-i-1]` might be the most confusing part of the code. Suppose `i = 0`, then `row[-0-1] #=> row[-1]`, which is the last element of `row`. When `i = 1`, `row[-1-1] #=> row[-2]`, which is the next-to-last element of `row`, and so on. That could instead be written `row[row.size-i-1]`.

Note `return` is not needed if, as here, the return value of the last statement executed (before the method returns) is to be returned by the method.

Let's add some `puts` statements in the method and work through an example.

```
def diagonal_difference(arr)
  puts "arr=#{arr}"
  main_diagonal_sum=0
  main_skew_diagonal_sum=0
  arr.each_with_index do |row, i|
    puts "row=#{row}, i=#{i}"
    main_diagonal_sum += row[i]
    puts "  row[#{i}]=#{row[i]}, main_diagonal_sum=#{main_diagonal_sum}"
    main_skew_diagonal_sum += row[-i-1]
    puts "  row[-#{i}-1]=#{row[-i-1]}, main_skew_diagonal_sum=#{main_skew_diagonal_sum}"
  end
  (main_diagonal_sum - main_skew_diagonal_sum).abs
end

arr = [[1,2,3],
       [4,5,6],
       [9,8,7]]
```

The main diagonal sum is `1+5+7 #=> 13` and the main skew diagonal sum is `3+5+9 #=> 17`, so we expect the method to return `(13-17).abs #=> 4`.

```
diagonal_difference(arr)
  #=> 4
```

prints the following.

```
arr=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [9, 8, 7]]
row=[1, 2, 3], i=0
  row[0]=1, main_diagonal_sum=1
  row[-0-1]=3, main_skew_diagonal_sum=3
row=[4, 5, 6], i=1
  row[1]=5, main_diagonal_sum=6
  row[-1-1]=5, main_skew_diagonal_sum=8
row=[9, 8, 7], i=2
  row[2]=7, main_diagonal_sum=13
  row[-2-1]=9, main_skew_diagonal_sum=17
```

---

This can alternatively be written as follows. We first need a helper method to rotate a square array 90 degrees.

```
def rotate90(arr)
  arr.map(&:reverse).transpose
end
```

```
arr = [[1,2,3],
       [4,5,6],
       [9,8,7]]
```

```
arr90 = rotate90(arr)
  #=>    [[3, 6, 7],
  #       [2, 5, 8],
  #       [1, 4, 9]]
```

Next, I'll add a second helper to sum the main diagonal of a square matrix. That's easiest by using [Matrix#trace](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-trace).

```
require 'matrix'
```

```
def trace(arr)
  Matrix[*arr].trace
end
```

We therefore may write the following.

```
(trace(arr90) - trace(arr)).abs
  #=> (17 - 13).abs => 4.abs => 4
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is a brilliant explanation and I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

See following

```
11 2 4
4 5 6
10 8 -12
So, a = [ [11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12] ]
```

Now ref [`each_with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index) method for `a.each_with_index do |array, index|`. during first iteration `array will be [11, 2, 4] & index will be 0`. `array[0] = 11` & `array[-0-1] i.e. array[-1] = 4`
Similarly for second iteration `array[1] = 5` & `array[-1-1] i.e. array[-2] = 5`& so on.

You'll get

```
2.3.1 :360 > left_right # 11 + 5 - 12
 => 4 
2.3.1 :361 > right_left # 4 + 5 + 10
 => 19 
2.3.1 :362 > v = right_left - left_right
 => 15
```

`v.abs` is used to return absolute difference in case `v is negative`, Ref [`abs`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-abs) method of `Numeric` class.

Note:- `return` keyword is optional if it is the last non comment line in a method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Matrix library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-tr) as proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32855117/5101493).

```
require 'matrix'
(Matrix[*arr].tr - Matrix[*arr.reverse].tr).abs
```

Where `arr` is an array of depth 2 with length `n` and each sub-array is also of length `n` e.g. `[[a,b],[c,d]]`.

Comment: I just happened to come back to this question and saw your answer. I'm wondering if I hadn't seen it when I posted my answer, because I had added  something similar as an alternative solution, but I now see that it was unnecessarily complex when compared to your answer. I therefore deleted that part of my answer, and apologize for not having done so at the time.

Comment: Hi @Cary no worries; I don't mind. I trust anything you did/do was/are with good intentions . The link in my answer references an one of your other SO answers so I should thank you for this! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Sidenote:* **NB** I am posting this as an answer, not a comment, for the sake of formatting; it should not be upvoted.

The more ruby idiomatic version of the snippet you have posted would be:

```
def diagonal_difference(a)
  a.each.with_object([0, 0]).with_index do |(e, left_right), idx|
    left_right[0] += array[idx]
    right_left[1] += array[-idx-1]
  end.reduce(:-).abs
end
```